# Unable to reconnect to linked tables ODBC VBA

Tags: mysql, ms-access, vba, odbc

I'm using MS Access 2007 with Win7 Professional x64.
I have to connect to an external MySQL database passing by the ODBC v5.1 local driver.

From VBA I'm able to connect to my database succesfully and from Access I can open my linked tables and see the data.

You can see below the code that I'm using to create the linked table. I dont want to use DSN way; I prefer the driver way.

```
Dim CnnString As String
Dim tdf As DAO.TableDef
CnnString = "ODBC;DRIVER=MySQL ODBC 5.1 Driver;DATABASE=xxxx;OPTION=2048;PORT=0;SERVER=xxxxx;UID=xxxxx;PWD=xxxx;Connect Timeout=45; Command Timeout=90;"
Set tdf = CurrentDb.CreateTableDef("table1")
tdf.Connect = CnnString
tdf.SourceTableName = "table1"
CurrentDb.TableDefs.Append tdf
Set tdf = Nothing
```

When I quit my VBA/Access application and I reopen it, the linked table appears in the tables list but if I double click on it, the ODBC connector windows appears asking me a DSN connection, I cannot see the data and my application doesn't work.

How can I make the connection to my linked table permanent?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Perhaps you should use `Port=3306;`?

Comment: After reopening the database, what Connect string does the linked table show? (Design view -> properties)

Comment: @Gustav: I've tried with port 3306 but it's the same. Connection is ok but after I quit and reopen my program, the ODBC connector window still appears and my application doesn't work.

Comment: @Andre451: after reopening the db the connect string is the right one used in the code in my post: "ODBC;DRIVER={MYSQL ODBC 5.1 Driver};DATABASE=xxxx;OPTION=2048;PORT=3306;SERVER=xxx;Connect Timeout=45;Command Timeout=90;;TABLE=table1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now I've had the chance to check how I did this...
I have successfully (and permanently) linked DSN-less ODBC tables with VBA using the [`DoCmd.TransferDatabase`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff196455.aspx) command:

```vb
' CnnString as above
DoCmd.TransferDatabase _
    TransferType:=acLink, _
    DatabaseType:="ODBC", _
    DatabaseName:=CnnString, _
    ObjectType:=acTable, _
    Source:="table1", _
    Destination:="table1", _
    StructureOnly:=False, _
    StoreLogin:=True
```

The important part is `StoreLogin:=True` -- I don't think you can specify this when using the `CreateTableDef` method.

Comment: Thanks a lot man, this solved my problem! thank you so much ^_^